# How to define interdependent functions in F#?

Tags: function, f#

I defined these two functions in F#

```
let f t = 
   match t with
   |_ when t = 0 -> 1
   |_ -> g t-1

let g t = 1 + (f t)
```

However, F# compiler didn't accept it. It said that

```
stdin(9,16): error FS0039: The value or constructor 'f' is not defined
```

Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: Also, if you pasted just that into a blank `fsi` you will get a message about `g` being undefined.  It is good to show the correct error message by starting a new `fsi` and rerunning all your code to ensure nothing is left from previous experiments

Answer (score 5, accepted):

F# supports mutual recusion using the `let rec ... and ...` syntax.  Here is your example

```
let rec f t = 
   match t with
   |_ when t = 0 -> 1
   |_ -> g t-1

and g t = 1 + (f t)
```